# Insert PHP Multidimensional Array to Mysql database using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I need to know the internal syntax in mysql to insert a bunch of data at once using on duplicate key.

I'm trying this but I have no the results desired(It is an example for practice):

**SQL query: INSERT INTO users (positive_number, negative_number, code) VALUES('23', '-23', 'rewe12314'),('2', '-2', 't4234df') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE positive_number=23, negative_number=-23,positive_number=2, negative_number=-2**

The insert part is correct, and I am assuming that I have incorrect the syntax for the on duplicate key update. Could you please tell me the correct syntax?

Here is my code:

```
 $users = array(
 array(
    'positive_number' => '23',
    'negative_number' => '-23',
    'code' => 'rewe12314',
 ),
 array(
    'positive_number' => '2',
    'negative_number' => '-2',
    'code' => 't4234df',
 )

 );

 echo "<br>";

 $total_rows = count($users);

 $values = array();
 for ($i = 0; $i < $total_rows; $i++) {


 $POSITIVE_NUMBER = $users[$i]['positive_number'];
 $NEGATIVE_NUMBER = $users[$i]['negative_number'];
 $CODE = $users[$i]['code'];

 $values[] = "('$POSITIVE_NUMBER', '$NEGATIVE_NUMBER', '$CODE')";
 $values_update[] = "positive_number=".$POSITIVE_NUMBER.", 
                    negative_number=".$NEGATIVE_NUMBER;

 }


 $sql = "INSERT INTO users (positive_number, negative_number, code) 
 VALUES";
 $sql.= implode(',',$values);
 $sql.= " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ";
 $sql.= implode(',',$values_update);

 echo "SQL query: " . $sql;
 if (!$conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
 echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 }
```

I think knowing the syntax I could solve the problem.
Thanks in advance for your help, Greetings!

Comment: I don't see where you executed the query and which api is used to connect with. All I see is that you're only echoing it. So it's hard to give you the right error handling reference.

Comment: I added that part to the snippet code, but I have no error thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple assignments in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause. What you can do instead is use the [`VALUES()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values) function to access the values for that particular insert in the `UPDATE` clause. So, just change these lines:

```
$sql.= " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ";
$sql.= implode(',',$values_update);
```

to:

```
$sql .= " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE positive_number=VALUES(positive_number),
                                  negative_number=VALUES(negative_number)";
```

See [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly what I need. Greetings !